# Get the total of a column in the report

Tags: powerbi

Very new to Power BI here! How can I get the total/sum of the entries of a column that is displayed in my report dashboard. [image]

I'm interested to get the total only from the column in the report, not from the table itself,
I tried SUM in column settings, but I get on that an astronomical number in billions, while the true number should be around 200K when choosing Do Not Summarize.

Comment: Could you explain how the total should be around 200K, while the smallest element is 464K? I'm afraid the logic behind your question is not quite clear.

Comment: This is a Measure? Propably you need to change calculated from sum to sumx

More info here:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/summing-values-for-the-total/

Comment: This is pretty much basic functionality, I'm guessing you have a lot more records in the table if you scroll down.